# Datatypes in groovy similar to java?

Tags: java, types, groovy

I am trying to figure out what is the similar datatype I should use in java similar to groovy?

My groovy code as follows

```
statistic = [:]
entries.each {
    minute = it.getRequestTime()

    value = it.getValue()

    if (statistic[minute] == null) {
        statistic[minute] = [:]
    }

    if (statistic[minute][value] == null) {
        statistic[minute][value] = ['count': 0L, 'timesum': 0L, 'min': Long.MAX_VALUE, 'max': Long.MIN_VALUE]
    }
}
```

I am new to groovy and its very hard to understand datatype they have used. I could understand that they have used Hashmap (`statistic = [:]`) in groovy. But the later is really confusing for me. Can anyone please help me to understand this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are nested maps, maps in maps.

```
if (statistic[minute] == null)
```

This means, if there's no entry for the `minute` key, put a new empty map there.

```
if (statistic[minute][value] == null)
```

This means, if there's no entry in `statistic[minute]`
for the key `value`, then put another map there.

Comment: Is it something like this `Map<Map<String,Map<String,String>>,Long>` for the last assignment statistic[minute][value] = ['count': 0L, 'timesum': 0L, 'min': Long.MAX_VALUE, 'max': Long.MIN_VALUE]?

Comment: Yes, they put a map into statistic[minute][value].

Comment: Assuming minute and value are strings, it's more like `Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Long>>>`